# Bing Maps V8 TypeScript package - Microsoft is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, bing-maps

I want to use BingMaps in my react (typescript) project.
I installed the npm bingmaps package, which brings the necessary d.ts.

I import the module via:

```
import 'bingmaps';
```

Inside my Component I do the fallowing:

```
public componentDidMount(){
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#map',
        {
            credentials: 'XXXXX',
            maxZoom: 6,
            minZoom: 2,
        });
};
```

At this point my app throws the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined

How do I import BingMaps correctly to include all necessary namespaces/modules?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I am try to use native bing maps v8 control from react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have prior familiarity with Bing Maps or ASP.NET JavaScript prerendering, but here are the results of my research.  The [`bingmaps` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bingmaps) just has the type declarations.  The actual implementation comes in a JavaScript file (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712557.aspx)), and I'm guessing the implementation is not compatible with prerendering.  So you'll need to either:

1. Disable prerendering completely by removing the `asp-prerender-*` attributes described in the [documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#server-side-prerendering) from your view, or
2. Skip prerendering just for this one React component by putting a test like `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` around the code as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1147#issuecomment-318338510).